# XSLT - how can I filter data source by data from external XML?

Tags: xpath, internet-explorer-7, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML data structure:

```
<root>
    <info>
      <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
    </info>
    <promotions>
      <promotion>
        <header>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>Name 1</name>
        </header>
        <positions>
              <position>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Some position name 1</name>
              </position>
              <position>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Some position name 2</name>
              </position>
          </position>
        </positions>
      </promotion>
      <promotion>
        <header>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>Name 2</name>
        </header>
        <positions>
          <position>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>Some position name 3</name>
          </position>
        </positions>
      </promotion>
    </promotions>
  </root>
```

Which is used as primary data source for my template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
...
```

I need to filter the above by **"filter.xml" file**, containing promotion Id's to filter out, and it needs to work on **IE7** . Is something like this possible?

For starters I tried to find a way to add filter in **xsl:apply-templates select** statement, so that **only promotion with Id=2 will be processed by template** but failed - is it possible to write Xpath that will say:

"Give me everything from root node but promotions only with Id = 2" ?

Thanks.

EDIT1:

Sorry about the namespace - it shouldn't be there in the first place. As for the filter.xml - it is not clearly defined yet - for now, I'm using the following:

```
<usedUpPromotions>
  <header>
    <promotionId>
      1
    </promotionId>
  </header>
  <header>
    <promotionId>
      2
    </promotionId>
  </header>
  <header>
    <promotionId>
      3
    </promotionId>
  </header>
</usedUpPromotions>
```

I think of using something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root[hereIsMyWhereId != (document('Load externalXmlHere')/select/IdtoFilterOut)"/>
```

But I can't seem to find a way to filter out data that way...

EDIT2:

I'll try to explain using code as example - let's assume for a moment that we have the following:

`XmlData initialXmlData;` <- this is  our XML data before filtering

`XmlData filter;` -< this contains the filter.xml data

```
Html GenerateHtmlFromTemplate(XmlData initialXmlData) - this is my Xslt template
{
...some precessing here
}
```

I would like to modify my template to achieve the following:

```
Html GenerateHtmlFromTemplate(XmlData initialXmlData, XmlData filter) 
{
XmlData filteredData = data.FilterBy(filter);
...same processing here as above, but use 'filteredData', instead of 'initialXmlData'
}
```

I hope it's more clear now :) - the main problem, it would seem is that the Id element, I want to filter by, is inside array variable, so I cannot simply use:

in my primary template - instead I bypassed the problem, by filtering on for-each loop later on but I would still like to know if it is possible to simply tell the template "from now on use filtered data, instead of original".

Edit3:

@michael.hor257k - to answer your question, I have modified templates you provided:

Template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ksx="http://www.test.com/test" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="no" method="html"/>

<root xmlns="http://www.test.com/test">
  <info>
    <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
  </info>
  <promotions>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id atr="tre">1</id>
        <name>Promotion 1</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>Position 1a</name>
        </position>
        <position>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>Position 1b</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Promotion 2</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>3</id>
          <name>Position 2a</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
  </promotions>
</root>

<xsl:param name="new-path" select="'new.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="new-promotions" select="document($new-path)/newPromotions/promotion" />



<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ksx:root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ksx:promotions/ksx:promotion[not(ksx:header/ksx:id=$new-promotions/header/id)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$new-promotions"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

new.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<newPromotions>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>New Promotion 2</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>New Position 2A</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>New Promotion 3</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>New Position 3A</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
</newPromotions>
```

If you save those, and open template.xml in Chrome it will work nicely - what I wanted however was to filter out data **outside** template node:

```
<xsl:template match="ksx:root">
```

So, I tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="ksx:root[ksx:promotion/ksx:header/ksx:id=1]">
```

And I expected to get all data from **root** but with promotions filtered to those with Id = 1 - but it gave all data and no errors, now I noticed that this:

```
<xsl:template match="ksx:root[ksx:promotions/ksx:promotion/ksx:header/ksx:id=$new-promotions/header/id]">
```

causes an error "Variables cannot be used within this expression" - so I guess, what I want to do is probably impossible from outside the template node...?

Sorry for the confusion - I hope now it is more clear. I simply wanted to treat template node as a method and "pass" filtered data to it, instead of filtering the data inside of it.

Edit4:

In my specific case, I have large "root" dataset of promotions, and small, external XML file that contains promotion Id's to hide during processing. So in my case filtering would mean: "Take everything from root element, but filter promotions so only those which Ids are NOT in the external file, will be processed". So if I have:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.test.com/test">
  <info>
    <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
  </info>
  <someData1>Some data 1</someData1>
  <someData2>Some data 2</someData2>
  <someData3>Some data 3</someData3>
  <promotions>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Promotion 1</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>Position 1a</name>
        </position>
        <position>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>Position 1b</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Promotion 2</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>3</id>
          <name>Position 2a</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Promotion 3</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>Position 3a</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
  </promotions>
</root>
```

And filter by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usedUpPromotions>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
</usedUpPromotions>
```

Then I would expect to get:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.test.com/test">
  <info>
    <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
  </info>
  <someData1>Some data 1</someData1>
  <someData2>Some data 2</someData2>
  <someData3>Some data 3</someData3>
  <promotions>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Promotion 3</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>Position 3a</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
  </promotions>
</root>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show us the contents of the filter.xml file, and the expected output of the transformation. -- Why is your template matching `tempNamespace:root` when your XML is in no-namespace?

Comment: I have no idea what "*filter out data outside template node*" means. Where is your input? And what is the expected output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k:

By "filter out" I mean filter out one XML by another - exactly what You did. For details please, see my edit4.

Comment: If it means exactly what I did, then where is the problem? Please see the extended response I have added to my answer.

Comment: @michael.hor257k:

Your solution works and there is no problem there - I just wonder if it is possible to apply this filtering as I shown im my edit3: on line <xsl:template match="ksx:root[ksx:promotion/ksx:header/ksx:id=1]">. My question is probably confusing because I'm pretty green to XSLT, and want to apply "programmer style" to XSLT and it doesn't fit in to well. To summarize - your solution works, I just wanted to know if it is possible to use something on the attribute level, instead of <xsl:copy> inside <xsl:template> element - now, I don't think it is possible in my specific case.

Comment: XSLT is a Turing-complete language, so anything is possible. The problem here is that I don't understand what you're saying. If you apply filtering only in a template's ***match pattern*** as you show, you will run into an issue of the other nodes being processed by the built-in templates. This too can be solved, but it's more convenient (at least in this case) to avoid the problem *a priori* by doing the filter in the apply- templates' ***select expression*** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process only promotions with Id=2, you can use (from the context of `root`):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="promotions/promotion[header/id='2']"/>
```

---

### Added:

Here's an example showing how you can "merge" your input XML with an overriding XML document. Given:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <info>
    <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
  </info>
  <promotions>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Promotion 1</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>Position 1a</name>
        </position>
        <position>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>Position 1b</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Promotion 2</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>3</id>
          <name>Position 2a</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
  </promotions>
</root>
```

**new.xml**

```
<newPromotions>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>New Promotion 2</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>New Position 2A</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
    <promotion>
      <header>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>New Promotion 3</name>
      </header>
      <positions>
        <position>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>New Position 3A</name>
        </position>
      </positions>
    </promotion>
</newPromotions>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="new-path" select="'path/to/new.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="new-promotions" select="document($new-path)/newPromotions/promotion" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="promotions">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="promotion[not(header/id=$new-promotions/header/id)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$new-promotions"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <info>
      <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
   </info>
   <promotions>
      <promotion>
         <header>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Promotion 1</name>
         </header>
         <positions>
            <position>
               <id>1</id>
               <name>Position 1a</name>
            </position>
            <position>
               <id>2</id>
               <name>Position 1b</name>
            </position>
         </positions>
      </promotion>
      <promotion>
         <header>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>New Promotion 2</name>
         </header>
         <positions>
            <position>
               <id>4</id>
               <name>New Position 2A</name>
            </position>
         </positions>
      </promotion>
      <promotion>
         <header>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>New Promotion 3</name>
         </header>
         <positions>
            <position>
               <id>5</id>
               <name>New Position 3A</name>
            </position>
         </positions>
      </promotion>
   </promotions>
</root>
```

---

### In response to your edit #4:

> So in my case filtering would mean: "Take everything from root
>   element, but filter promotions so only those which Ids are NOT in the
>   external file, will be processed".

My answer above does two things:

1. It copies everything from the input XML document **except** promotions whose IDs **are** in the external file;
2. It **adds** all the promotions listed in the external file.

If you only want to do #1 but not #2, then change this:

```
<xsl:template match="promotions">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="promotion[not(header/id=$new-promotions/header/id)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$new-promotions"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="promotions">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="promotion[not(header/id=$new-promotions/header/id)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In the given example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <info>
      <creationDate>2015-03-11 11:45:49</creationDate>
   </info>
   <promotions>
      <promotion>
         <header>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Promotion 1</name>
         </header>
         <positions>
            <position>
               <id>1</id>
               <name>Position 1a</name>
            </position>
            <position>
               <id>2</id>
               <name>Position 1b</name>
            </position>
         </positions>
      </promotion>
   </promotions>
</root>
```

Comment: This actually pointed me to right track, and I solved the problem by filtering later on, thanks. Still I would like to ask what do You mean by "from the context of root"? Do You mean I should call <xsl:apply-templates select="promotions/promotion[header/id='2']"/> inside : <xsl:template match="root"> ? I tried it, but either I don't understand something or this will simply write matched data out in the browser window. I'm looking for a way to substitute current data with the filtered on, so everything onward would use filtered out data...

Comment: @user2384366 I cannot answer your question because I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish - esp. the part about "*substitute current data with the filtered on*".

Comment: @user2384366 I am afraid that's still too vague. I have added an example to my answer - see if you can adapt it to your situation.

Comment: Please see my edit3 - I think this will finally make it clear, what I wanted to achieve :)